# Split strings into variables line by line, from all files within a directory

Tags: python, string, file, variables, split

I have files stored inside of a directory.
All of the files contain either paths/path like this or they are empty, file f:

```
folder1\folder2\Module.c
folder1\folder3\Module1.c
folder1\folder4\Module2.c
```

I need some function that will go through all lines inside of all files one by one, split strings and assign to variables:

```
folder1\folder2\Module.c -> variableA = folder1, variable2 = folder2, variable 3 = Module.c
```

Then I have to do something with this variables, and after it continue to second line:

```
  folder1\folder3\Module1.c -> variableA = folder1, variable2 = folder3, variable 3 = Module1.c
```

Have already tried something like this:

```
for f in files:
    with open(f, "r") as file:
        content = file.read()
        lines = content.split('\n')
        line = lines.split('\\', maxsplit=3)
        new_lines = []
        for l in line:
            new_lines.append(line)
        with open(f, "w") as file:
            file.write("\n".join(new_lines))
```

Any help and assistance is very welcome.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What attempt have you done already?

Comment: I will now edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def function(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read().split('\n')
        for line in content:
            if not line: continue
            var1, var2, var3 = line.split('\\')
            # do your thing with var1, var2, var3
            # print(var3)


# in your main code #
for filename in filenames:
    function(filename)
```

so `content` stores all the lines in the file you're reading, in a list. Each list item is one line.

```
['folder1\\folder2\\Module.c', 'folder1\\folder3', '\\Module1.c', 'folder1\\folder4\\Module2.c']
```

Then iterating thought the `content` list, `.split('\\')` methods splits each line by the `\` character

is this the answer you're looking for?

Comment: `for line in file:` is easier and more idiomatic than splitting on a newline and then iterating. Also, since `file` is a built-in function, using another variable name (like `fp`, for filepointer`) may be better.

Comment: May need to add the `maxsplit=3` argument back.

Comment: I think this might be it! Will let you know as soon as I test solution

Comment: I keep getting error: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1), not sure how empty files will be handled, since in folder there are some

Comment: are the empty files completely empty? sometimes they will still contain one single empty line with no characters in it, but its still 1 line and not 100% empty.. this current code works for completely empty files because `content` will be an empty list and never goes into the for loop.

Comment: I've updated the answer now to accommodate for this, maybe this time it will work?